# how do i remove specific letters from alphabet string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the alphabet as an uppercase string.

How do I remove the letters B G R P? I am using JavaScript.

I have tried:

replace(^/B/G/R/P/g, "")
replace(^[B,G,R,P]/g, "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php, would be somthing like this -

```
$string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$remove = preg_replace('/[BGRP]/', '', $string); 
// new string 
echo $remove;
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl, it's pretty easy, but regex has small differences in difference languages.

```
$myString =~ s/[BGRP]//g;
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript this would be something like this. ( with in case sensitive modifier )

```
var myOldString = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var myNewString = myOldString.replace(/[bgrp]/gi, ''); 
console.log(myNewString);
```